# I'm a little confused by the structure of the sentence. How to understand "suspicious treats through the fence"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I met a sentence on Twitter:

> Russia is like an oddly solicitous neighbor who you eventually find out is stealing your mail and feeding your dog suspicious treats through the fence.

(https://twitter.com/MelissaAmour72/status/976048405666549760)

As an English learner, I'm a little confused by the structure of the sentence. How to understand "suspicious treats through the fence"?

My analysis is:

Russia [subject]

is [link-verb]

like an oddly solicitous neighbor [predicative]

who you eventually find out [attributive clause modifying "neighbor"]

is stealing your mail and feeding your dog [object clause]

suspicious treats through the fence. [???]

Answer (score 1):

This sentence has a compound predicates:

`stealing your mail`

AND

`feeding your dog` (indirect object) `suspicious treats` (direct object) `through the fence` (prepositional phrase)

Comment: Then why "treats" not "a treat"?